# Многомерный массив в JS?

Tags: php, javascript

Как можно создать многомерный массив в js по типу:

```
$arr[] = array('type' => 1, 'title' => 'N');
```

Так получается?

```
var arr = [];

for(i = 0; i<input.length; i++){
   arr[i].type = 1;
   arr[i].title = 'N';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В js нет ассоциативных массивов, есть объекты

```
var structure = {
    type: 1,
    title: "N"
};
```

Конкретно с приведенным примером будет так:

```
for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = {
        type: 1,
        title: "N"
    };
}
```

или

```
for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = {};
    arr[i].type = 1;
    arr[i].title = 'N';
}
```

Comment: Такое возможно, когда j меняется? 
 
 `j = 'sub';
 arr[i][j].type = 1;`

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, я не просто так *инициализирую* объект. Из ниоткуда он не появится. `arr[i] = {};` и потом `arr[i][j] = {}` - можно.